# Suppose that both $p$ and $p^2 +2$ are prime numbers. Show that $p=3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can someone help me out with this? I've been working on it for quite a long time but I'm not sure if I'm even getting anywhere.

Comment: What routes have you tried?

Comment: well i've been working with the fact that since p is prime p^2 + 2 is prime, p can't  be even, and thus p^2 is congruent to 1 mod 4. But i'm now doubting that that is the correct route

Comment: @user228386, Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234077/prime-p-with-p28-prime

Comment: Related (for what it's worth): [$p^3 + 2$ is prime if $p$ and $p^2 + 2$ are prime?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023979)

Answer (score 9):

If $p$ is a prime other than 3, then $p \equiv 1 \bmod 3$ or $p \equiv 2 \bmod 3$. But either way $p^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 3$, which means that $p^2 + 2 \equiv 0 \bmod 3$, which means $p^2 + 2$ must be composite. But if $p = 3$, then $p^2 + 2 = 11$, which is prime.

If you're not convinced, try out a few cases of $p^2 + 2$:

- $5^2 + 2 = 27 = 3^3$
- $7^2 + 2 = 51 = 3 \times 17$
- $11^2 + 2 = 123 = 3 \times 41$
- etc.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Suppose $p \neq 3$. What does that mean is true of $p \mod 3$? What does that mean for $p^2 \mod 3$?